# Facebook open graph custom story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-permissions

I'm working on a project where users can give us `publish_actions` from the app, to able our backend publish a `Custom Open Graph Story` when some conditions are accomplished.

The flow is:

1. User login with Facebook on our app
2. User buys a ticket
3. User click on share story on facebook button, at this point publish_actions for user are requested
4. The app call a REST endpoint and the backend uses user token to send and open graph story

We tested this flow with our accounts (included as develeopers on facebook so act as a test-user) and it works as expected.

In order to allow this feature for the rest of users, we should send a submission review for `publish_action` permission? And also for our open graph story?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> n order to allow this feature for the rest of users, we should send a submission review for publish_action permission? And also for our open graph story?

Yes, of course you need to get both reviewed, before regular users can be asked for that permission, and publish that OG story.